# Upgraded to Angular 4.1.2 from 2.4 and now why does it requires absolute Urls?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Spatemplates and am now running on angular 4.1.2. When I was using the previous version of the Spatemplates that was using angular 2.4 I was able to do a http.get to my .NET controller with an angular service with the code you see below using a relative url.

```
export class MyService {
private url = 'api/myController';

constructor(private _http: Http) {
}
public getAll = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this._http.get(this.url)
        .map(data => data.json());
};
```

Now that I am using the new Spatemplates it is requiring an absolute URL. Does anyone know why this is?

Also I know have noticed in my app.module.client.ts I see an ORIGIN_URL

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
]
```

I'm assuming that I need to use the ORIGIN_URL in my service, but not quite sure how to inject it in there. I just didn't think I should have to use this url: 
 "http://localhost:{port#}/api/myController" in my service. Am I correct in thinking this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject, and use that provider 'ORIGIN_URL', you do it with constructor injection like this.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

...
export class MyService {
    private url = '/api/myController';

    constructor(private _http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') private originUrl: string) {
    }
    public getAll = (): Observable<any> => {
        return this._http.get(this.originUrl + this.url)
            .map(data => data.json());
    };
}
```

I can't say for sure why the relative URL no longer works.